# Ubuntu - sudo snap install postman not working

Tags: postman, ubuntu-20.04

Getting a error while trying to install postman with `snap`

```sh
~$:sudo snap install postman

error: cannot install "postman": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp:
       lookup api.snapcraft.io: no such host
```

Tried to get it working with these commands and got the following errors:

```sh
~$ sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
~$ sudo systemctl status snapd
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     
Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-03-28 18:06:00 EET; 2h 11min ago

TriggeredBy: ● snapd.socket
   Main PID: 13249 (snapd)
      Tasks: 20 (limit: 4545)
     Memory: 26.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
             └─13249 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

مار 28 18:05:57 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
مار 28 
18:05:57 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 systemd[1]: Starting Snap Daemon...
مار 28 
18:05:58 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled an>
مار 28 
18:05:59 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled an>
مار 28 
18:05:59 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: daemon.go:347: started snapd/2.49.1 (se>
مار 28 
18:05:59 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: daemon.go:440: adjusting startup timeou>
مار 28 
18:06:00 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 systemd[1]: Started Snap Daemon.
مار 28 
18:06:00 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: autorefresh.go:472: Cannot prepare auto>
مار 28 
18:06:00 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: stateengine.go:150: state ensure error:>
مار 28 
18:13:37 muhammed-Inspiron-5558 snapd[13249]: api.go:383: Installing snap "postman" r>

~$ sudo snap refresh core

error: cannot refresh "core": Post https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: 
       lookup api.snapcraft.io: no such host
```

Comment: thats a dns issue try disabling and reenabling dns . see if you have are able to use internet and dns is being resolved correctly